# how to find the references of the save(...) method of a spring data repository subtype

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, reference, spring-data-jpa

A project uses spring-data repositories.

I need to find all the places in the project where a particular type of entities saved.

Let's say that persons are stored in a table called PERSONS. There is a repository for persons:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>
```

And the persons are saved like this:

```
@Autowired
private PersonRepository personRepository;
...
personRepository.save(...)
```

I would like to find all the places where the PersonRepository.save(...) called. I can't use text search because the names of the repository objects are not standard in the project.

Is there a way to do this in Eclipse (or in other IDE) ?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse:

1. Right click on the Repository Interface name.
2. Click on "references"
3. Click on "Project"

You will get a list of all classes where the repository is auto-wired across the project. You can then see if save is used or not in the class. Not exactly what you want but somewhat near.

Comment: I have tried that already. The problem is that the repository is used many many places for various queries. So I would be happy to find an easier and more accurate method.